# Counting the number of response codes in JMeter 4.0

Tags: api, jmeter, timeout, assertion

I run some load tests (all endpoints) and we do have a known issue in our code: if multiple POST requests are sent in the same time we do get a duplicate error based on a timestamp field in our database.

All I want to do is to count timeouts (based on the message received "Service is not available. Request timeout") in a variable and accept this as a normal behavior (don't fail the tests).

For now I've added a Response Assertion for this (in order to keep the tests running) but I cannot tell if or how many timeout actually happen.

How can I count this? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend doing this as follows:

1. Add [JSR223 Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) to your Test Plan
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   if (prev.getResponseDataAsString().contains('Service is not available. Request timeout')) {
       prev.setSampleLabel('False negative')
   }
   ```

That's it, if sampler will contain  `Service is not available. Request timeout` in the response body - JMeter will change its title to `False negative`.

[image: JMeter Conditionally Amend Sampler name]

You can even mark it as passed by adding `prev.setSuccessful(false)` line to your script. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article fore more information on what else you can do with Groovy in JMeter tests

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to find out the count based on the response message then you can save the performance results in a csv file using simple data writer (configure for csv only) and then filter csv based on the response message to get the required count. Or you can use Display only "errors" option to get all the errors and then filter out based on the expected error message.

If you need to find out at the runtime then you can use aggregate report listener and use "Errors" checkbox to get the count of failure but this will include other failures also.

But, if you need to get the count at the run time to use it later then it is a different case. I am assuming that it is not the case.

Thanks,

Comment: We are trying to improve the code to get as less "timeouts" as possible. I just need to keep track of them. I will go with the second case. Thank you